# GUI development package

Tags: python, linux, user-interface

I am new to GUI development. What is the best GUI development package for python on linux (ubuntu being more specific)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous decent GUI toolkits, the most popular being PyQt, PyGTK, wxPython and Tkinter. Personally, I prefer Qt, but that's really subjective.

Comment: Qt it is then! Thats true but i needed an opinion before i started off working with any package. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is Qt4 designer something like Glade for pyQt?

Comment: @san8055: Yes it is. It's good for whipping up the initial structure, but since some of the really cool widgets that I happen to need sometimes can't be placed in the designer, I decided to sketch out the interface via designer as far as possible and add the rest by hand.

Comment: I've been using wxPython with some success there are some nice python extensions, and I've been able to make my own widgets as needed- I'm tempted to try QT for my next project though, as I've heard many good things about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more a matter of personal taste.

I use GTK+ with Glade.

Comment: Galde looks like a wonderful package.. is it something like fireworks or something for designing how gui will look?

Comment: Yes. I prefer to face it like a simpler version of netbeans, hehehe.